# Minimizing the distance between two sums of ratios

Tags: optimization

I have an optimization problem which I think might be fairly difficult, so I want to ask if it's practically possible.

To start out, I have a linear programming problem, for which I obtain the optimal objective value. The problem has multiple optimal solutions. Next, I want to investigate possible solutions subject to the objective value being at least a given fraction of the optimal value (so, just another linear constraint). Specifically, I want to minimize the euclidean distance between two vectors, one of them given and the other being a vector of ratios of variables in the problem. Are there any algorithms available that can solve this problem?

The problem has typically at least 100 variables, and the matrix A in Ax = 0 is sparse. Here's an attempt at formulating the problem:

\begin{gathered}
  \min \sum\limits_i {{{\left( {\frac{{{x_{a(i)}}}}{{{x_{b(i)}}}}} \right)}^2} - 2{y_i}\left( {\frac{{{x_{a(i)}}}}{{{x_{b(i)}}}}} \right)}  \\
  s.t: \\
  Ax = 0  \\
  Z = {c^T}x \\
  {\alpha _i} \leqslant {x_i} \leqslant {\beta _i} \\
  Z \geqslant {Z^ * } \\
0 \leqslant {Z^ *} \leqslant {Z_{\max}}
\end{gathered}